# Drawing numbered balls from an urn and summing numbers

Tags: probability

We draw $n$ balls from an urn which contains $2n$ numbered balls.

The balls are numbered with $1,2,\dots,2n$.

Moreover it is given that:

- $n$ is odd.
- $S$ = sum of values of the $n$ balls we draw.
- $R$ = sum of values of the remaining balls in the urn.

Please help to calculate the probability that $S > R$.

No clue how to start... thank you

Comment: Consider the symmetry of the situation, which is probably the point of the problem.  You will need to explicitly calculate the chances that $S = R$.  Once you do that, the symmetry will kick in.  It would help if you could confirm that the balls are numbered $\{1,2,3, \cdots, (2n)\}.$

Comment: Thank you - yes the balls are numbered from 1 to 2n and n is odd... I tried to think about p(S=R) but didnt know what to do

Comment: You must edit and add in your question that $n$ is odd. That is essential information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$S+R=1+2+\cdots+2n=n(2n+1)$$ so if $n$ is odd then $S+R$ is odd and consequently $S=R$ is not possible.

Now use the symmetry suggested in the comment of user2661923.

Comment: How would you have attacked the case of $n$ even?

Comment: @user2661923  Things might be quite difficult to find if that is not given. Then we should have to go for $P(S=\frac12n(2n+1))$. Fortunately that is not necessary because the OP commented that $n$ is odd. I haven't thought of an attack yet for even $n$ but only observed that it is probably not easy.

Comment: Thank you so much! so I guess that if p(S=R)=0 then p(S>R)=1/2

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you again

Comment: You are welcome.